# Error in running AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am running AVD on Anroid Studio 2.1.2 and got

- Error" Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!"
- AVD appears as black screen only

--> Can you suggest a solution. Thanks

[image]

Comment: does enabling/disabling snapshot in avd settings help??

Answer (score 2):

Go to `AVD Manager` -> `Select the device` -> click `Edit` and uncheck the Enabled checkbox

[image]